# Probability of flipping 7 cards into the trashcan

Tags: probability

I'm flipping cards from my cot into a trashcan across the room. I make 20% of my shots. What is the probability that I make 7 cards using a single deck?

Comment: What kinda deck?

Comment: A regular 52 card deck.

Comment: This is a binomial distribution,not a negative binomial distribution

Comment: Exactly 7, or at least 7?

Comment: Exactly 7. Why is it a binomial distribution?

Comment: I've edited the title -- pls try to pick a title that summarises the problem / what you're asking. I'm also going to edit the other question you made that had the same title of "Negative binomial".

Answer (score 1):

Probability of success=0.20

Number of trials=52

$$P(X=7)={52\choose7}\cdot (0.2)^7\cdot (0.8)^{52-7}=0.0745873846=7.46\%$$

if you mean atleast 7,

$$P(X\ge7)=1-P(X<7)$$
$$P(X\ge7)=1-\sum_{k=0}^7{52\choose k}\cdot(0.2)^k\cdot(0.8)^{52-k}$$